# Webapp running in Eclipse, but getting 404 error when running directly from Tomcat outside Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, http, tomcat7

I have a web application (Spring MVC, REST in java) in Eclipse. When I am running it in Tomcat from inside Eclipse, the webpages are opening successfully.

Then I am trying to run the app from Tomcat directly. For this I went to the webapps folder in Tomcat7 and put the war file of the app (I exported the project from Eclipse as war file). After this I went to the bin folder of Tomcat and double clicked on the tomcat7.exe file. 
After this when I am trying to open the webpage as:

```
http://localhost:8080/SpringMVCClient/login.htm
```

I am getting the error:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /SpringMVCClient/login.htm

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Status report

message /SpringMVCClient/login.htm

description The requested resource (/SpringMVCClient/login.htm) is not available.
```

Can you please help me find out what I am missing here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled Apache Tomcat and now everything is working fine!